# Find the number of all possible path in a grid, from (0, 0) to (n, n)

Tags: algorithm

I don't know how to find the number of all possible path in a grid, from a Point A to a Point B.
The point A is on (0,0) and the point B is on (n,n).
A can move up, down, right, and left, and can't move on visited points.
While A moving, A(x,y) = (x,y|(0=<x=<n)∩(0=<y=<n)).

Comment: This kind of reads like something from a so-called "competition" or "online-judge" site. If you're new to programming or the C++ language, please step away from such sites. They are not teaching or learning resources, and using them as such will be harmful to your advancement as a programmer. Invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and take classes. Don't use such sites until you know programming, C++ and how to write good and maintainable code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would guess this to be a homework problem. Meant to demonstrate how a small change in statement takes a problem from easy to optimize to very hard to optimize.  If you can just move right and down, it is easy.  With all 4 directions, it is hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with recursive backtracking, but there's another approach which I think is more interesting.

If we work out the first few cases by hand we find that:

- A 1x1 square has 1 path
- A 2x2 square has 2 paths
- A 3x3 square has 12 paths

If we then go to [OEIS (the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences)](https://oeis.org/) and put in the search phrase "1,2,12 paths", the very first result is [A007764](https://oeis.org/A007764) which is entitled "Number of nonintersecting (or self-avoiding) rook paths joining opposite corners of an n X n grid".

Knowing what integer sequence you're looking for unlocks significant mathematical resources, including source code to generate the sequence, related sequences, and best-known values.

The known values of the sequence are:

```
1 1
2 2
3 12
4 184
5 8512
6 1262816
7 575780564
8 789360053252
9 3266598486981642
10 41044208702632496804
11 1568758030464750013214100
12 182413291514248049241470885236
13 64528039343270018963357185158482118
14 69450664761521361664274701548907358996488
15 227449714676812739631826459327989863387613323440
16 2266745568862672746374567396713098934866324885408319028
17 68745445609149931587631563132489232824587945968099457285419306
18 6344814611237963971310297540795524400449443986866480693646369387855336
19 1782112840842065129893384946652325275167838065704767655931452474605826692782532
20 1523344971704879993080742810319229690899454255323294555776029866737355060592877569255844
21 3962892199823037560207299517133362502106339705739463771515237113377010682364035706704472064940398
22 31374751050137102720420538137382214513103312193698723653061351991346433379389385793965576992246021316463868
23 755970286667345339661519123315222619353103732072409481167391410479517925792743631234987038883317634987271171404439792
24 55435429355237477009914318489061437930690379970964331332556958646484008407334885544566386924020875711242060085408513482933945720
25 12371712231207064758338744862673570832373041989012943539678727080484951695515930485641394550792153037191858028212512280926600304581386791094
26 8402974857881133471007083745436809127296054293775383549824742623937028497898215256929178577083970960121625602506027316549718402106494049978375604247408
27 17369931586279272931175440421236498900372229588288140604663703720910342413276134762789218193498006107082296223143380491348290026721931129627708738890853908108906396
```

You can generate the first few terms yourself on paper or via recursive backtracking, per the other answer.

Comment: This is a great approach to know about. But I was trying to leave work to do in case my guess is correct that this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest solving this with naive recursion.

Keep a set `visted` of places that you have visited.  And in pseudo-code that is deliberately not any particular language:

```
function recursive_call(i, j, visited=none)
    if visited is none then
        visited = set()
    end if
    if i = n and j = n then
        return  1
    else if (i, j) in visited or not in grid then
        return 0
    else
        total = 0
        add (i, j) to visited
        for direction in directions:
            (new_i, new_j) = move(i, j, direction)
            total += recursive_call(new_i, new_j, visited)
        remove (i, j) from visited
        return total
    end if
end function
```